# ¿"Faltaría menos" o "faltaría mas"? ¿Existen ambas?

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones

Ayer escuché a alguien que usaba tanto ***faltaría menos*** como ***faltaría más*** en la misma conversación. Hasta hoy conocía solo la segunda, ***faltaría más***.

Entonces, ¿existen las dos frases? ¿En cuál contexto se utiliza la primera y en cuál la segunda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el diccionario se recoge únicamente la versión con "más", en la entrada para *[faltar](https://dle.rae.es/faltar)*. Tienes estas dos variantes:

- Faltaría más.
- No faltaba más.

Curiosamente, tiene dos acepciones que parecen contradecirse un poco:

> 1. expr. Usada para rechazar una proposición por absurda o inadmisible.
> 2. expr. Usada para manifestar la disposición favorable al cumplimiento de lo que se ha requerido.

La variante con *menos* no la encuentro documentada en el CORDE, y en el CREA solo aparece un caso de un registro oral:

> *Y bebíamos mucho aguardiente ahí, sabroso. ¡Pues! No faltaba menos ¿verdad?*
>
> Oral, CSHC-87 Entrevista 140, Venezuela.

Buscando [en Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faltar%C3%ADa%20m%C3%A1s%2C%20faltar%C3%ADa%20menos&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaltar%C3%ADa%20m%C3%A1s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfaltar%C3%ADa%20menos%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfaltar%C3%ADa%20m%C3%A1s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfaltar%C3%ADa%20menos%3B%2Cc0) y en la propia Google, los resultados de "faltaría más" son entre uno y dos órdenes de magnitud superiores a los de "faltaría menos", la cual parece que en los últimos años está ganando un poco de fama. La propia RAE [ha reconocido en Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/955102924958552064) que, si bien la variante con "menos" no constituye una fórmula de cortesía, sí que "a veces se emplea para señalar que lo mencionado se considera el colmo, algo que no es de recibo".

Así pues, existir existen ambas porque ambas se usan y se entienden, aunque el DLE solo recoge (de momento) la variante con "más".

Comment: No es de extrañar que las dos acepciones sean diametralmente opuestas, puesto que la primera parece ser sarcástica, ¿no?.  Algo parecido a "lo que faltaba".

Answer (score 2):

El DLE solo incluye "[faltaría más](https://dle.rae.es/faltar)", con dos significados aparentemente opuestos:

> 1. expr. U. para rechazar una proposición por absurda o inadmisible.
> 2. expr. U. para manifestar la disposición favorable al cumplimiento de lo que se ha requerido.

Parece ser por tanto que la expresión original es "faltaría más". El capítulo de libro "[*(No) faltaba/faltaría más.*  Creación y desarrollo  de un marcador de confirmación  y rechazo](https://edizionicafoscari.unive.it/media/pdf/books/978-88-6969-381-6/978-88-6969-381-6-ch-04.pdf)" [1], hace un análisis extenso de esta expresión. En la página 106, dice:

> Realmente, la falta de función específica del adverbio *más* en la construcción gramaticalizada *(no) faltaría más* se mostraba también en la alteración de esta secuencia en *(no) faltaría menos* con la misma función [...]

y también se indica que el uso de la expresión con el adverbio *más* es más frecuente. Google corrobora esta afirmación: hay 781000 resultados para "[faltaría más](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22faltar%C3%ADa%20m%C3%A1s%22)", y solo 11700 resultados para "[faltaría menos](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%22faltar%C3%ADa%20menos%22)".

---

[1]
Francisco Javier Herrero Ruiz de Loizaga, "[(No) faltaba/faltaría más. Creación y desarrollo de un marcador de confirmación y rechazo,](https://edizionicafoscari.unive.it/media/pdf/books/978-88-6969-381-6/978-88-6969-381-6-ch-04.pdf)" en *[Lexicalización, léxico y lexicografía en la historia del español [ebook]](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/libro?codigo=777525)* / coord. por Florencio del Barrio de la Rosa, 2019, ISBN 978-88-6969-381-6, págs. 81-113

Answer (score -1):

Se me salió decir el otro día, faltaría menos, y en seguida dudé de mí mismo. Lo dije cuando un cliente se ofreció a hacer no sé que gestión adicional, laboriosa e innecesaria. Quería decir más o menos que no era para nada necesario y que mucho menos esperaba que lo hiciera.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/26033)